# How to export "filtered play" audio only on RavenPro

Tags: soundtrap, raven, filter, audio, background-noise

So I'm using RavenPro to analyse recordings from hydrophones in the indian ocean and trying to export sound clips of humpback whale calls but I wanted to know if there is a way to export filtered audio. I know that by selecting filtered audio I can listen to only the frequencies in a selection, but is there a way I can save an audio clip with only that frequency range rather than the entire range please?
I've looked in the manual but can't seem to find anything so any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Managed to find a solution after talking to RavenPro. If you highlight the range that you're looking to filter, like you would for filtered playback and then click on Edit>Band Filter > Filter around active selection. It removes the any noise that isn't within the selected range. You can then save this active selection by clicking on File>Save Active Selection As...

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the "batch band filter" option. You'd have to first save your unfiltered audio clips in a new folder, then use the batch function to filter everything in that new folder. It's an extra step, and I wish there was a way to just save filtered or amplified clips any time. Maybe someone else knows the solution.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have to have a go at that. Hopefully there is a shortcut but if not that helps. Cheers